# the boxservo works contrary to the code

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, servo, project

i want to make a uselessbox .i connected the circuit correctly,i  checked every thing several times and every thing is in right place[ based on  descriptions and pattern],but when i turn  it on,the box servo closes the door and then handservo starts to turn off the switch ,the code says:[the boxservo opens the door then handservo starts to turn off the switch,when the switch  is off and handservo returned to its place then boxservo closes the door]but my box works like this(the boxservo closes the door then handservo starts to turn off the switch,when the switch  is off and handservo returned to its place,then boxservo opens the door).what should i do to solve this problem?[Useless box wiring and code](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/70885)

this is the code that i have uploaded:

```
#include <Servo.h>                        

Servo handServo;                          
Servo boxServo;

int switchStatus=0, action=1, vot, randNumber=0;                 
const int ledPin = 13;                    
const int frontSwitchPin = 2;
const int handServoPin = 5;
const int boxServoPin = 6;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);                  
  digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);

  handServo.attach(handServoPin);              
  boxServo.attach(boxServoPin);
  handServo.write(180);                        
  boxServo.write(70);

  //randomSeed(analogRead(0));
}


void loop()
{
  switchStatus = digitalRead(frontSwitchPin); 
  //action = random(1,16);

  if (switchStatus == LOW){                   

    if (action == 1)
    {
      Serial.println("Action 1");          
      for (int i = 70; i <= 110; i++)
      {
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(20);
      }
      for (int i = 180; i >= 35; i--)
      {
        handServo.write(i);
        delay(20);
      }
      delay(1000);
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(200);
      for (int i = 26; i <=180; i++)
      {
        handServo.write(i);
        delay(20);
      }
      for (int i = 110; i >= 70; i--)
      {
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(20);
      }
      action++;
    }


    else if (action == 2)
    {
      Serial.println("Action 2");         
      for (int i = 70; i <= 110; i++){
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(6);
      }
      delay(550);
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(550);
      handServo.write(180);
      delay(550);
      boxServo.write(70);
      delay(1500);
      for (int i = 70; i <= 110; i++){
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(6);
      }
      delay(3000);
      boxServo.write(70);
      action++;
    }

    else if (action == 3)
    {
      Serial.println("Action 3");         
      for (int i = 70; i <= 110; i++){
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(6);
      }
      delay(1000);
      boxServo.write(70);
      delay(2000);
      for (int i = 70; i <= 110; i++){
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(6);
      }
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(550);
      handServo.write(180);
      delay(500);
      boxServo.write(70);
      action++;
    }

    else if (action == 4)
    {
      Serial.println("Action 4");         
      for (int i = 70; i <= 110; i++)
      {
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(20);
      }
      for (int i = 180; i >= 35; i--)
      {
        handServo.write(i);
        delay(20);
      }
      delay(2000);
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(200);
      handServo.write(180);
      delay(400);
      boxServo.write(70);
      action++;
    }

    else if (action == 5)
    {
      Serial.println("Action 5");     
      for (int i = 70; i <= 110; i++){
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(6);
      }
      delay(2000);
      handServo.write(65);
      delay(550);
      handServo.write(40);
      delay(200);
      handServo.write(65);
      delay(200);
      handServo.write(40);
      delay(200);
      handServo.write(65);
      delay(200);
      handServo.write(40);
      delay(200);
      handServo.write(65);
      delay(200);
      handServo.write(40);
      delay(200);
      handServo.write(65);
      delay(200);
      handServo.write(40);
      delay(200);
      handServo.write(65);
      delay(2000);
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(400);
      handServo.write(180);
      delay(400);
      boxServo.write(70);
      action++;
    }

    else if (action == 6)             
    {
      Serial.println("Action 6");      
      for (int i = 70; i <110; i++)
      {
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(20);
      }
      delay(1000);
      for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 70; j <= 110; j++){
          boxServo.write(j);
          delay(6);
        }
        delay(200);
      }
      for (int i = 180; i >= 35; i--)
      {
        handServo.write(i);
        delay(30);
      }
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(400);
      handServo.write(180);
      delay(400);
      boxServo.write(70);
      delay(1500);
      for (int i = 70; i <= 110; i++){
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(6);
      }
      delay(3000);
      boxServo.write(80);
      action++;
    }

    else if (action == 7)
    {
      Serial.println("Action 7");      
      for (int i = 70; i <= 110; i++){
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(6);
      }
      delay(400);
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(1000);
      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 70; j <= 110; j++){
          boxServo.write(j);
          delay(6);
        }
        delay(200);
      }
      delay(500);
      handServo.write(180);
      delay(400);
      boxServo.write(70);
      action++;
    }

    else if (action == 8)
    {
      Serial.println("Action 8");    
      for (int i = 70; i <= 110; i++){
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(6);
      }
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(2000);
      for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
      {
        handServo.write(75);
        delay(100);
        handServo.write(40);
        delay(100);
      }
      delay(500);
      handServo.write(180);
      delay(1000);
      boxServo.write(70);
      action++;
    }

    else if (action == 9)
    {
      Serial.println("Action 9");      
      for (int i = 70; i <= 105; i++){
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(6);
      }
      delay(2000);
      boxServo.write(110);
      for (int i = 180; i >=35; i--)
      {
        handServo.write(i);
        delay(40);
      }
      delay(500);
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(200);
      for (int i = 26; i <=180; i++)
      {
        handServo.write(i);
        delay(40);
      }
      boxServo.write(70);
      delay(2000);
      boxServo.write(100);
      delay(3000);
      boxServo.write(70);
      action++;
    }


    else if (action == 10)
    {
      Serial.println("Action 10");      
      for (int i = 70; i <= 105; i++)
      {
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(100);
      }
      delay(1000);
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 70; j <= 100; j++){
          boxServo.write(j);
          delay(6);
      }
        delay(100);
      }
      boxServo.write(110);
      delay(100);
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(650);
      handServo.write(180);
      delay(400);
      boxServo.write(70);
      action++;
    }

    else if (action == 11)
    {
      Serial.println("Action 11");     
      for (int i = 70; i <= 110; i++){
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(6);
      }
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(2000);
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
        handServo.write(65);
        delay(200);
        handServo.write(40);
        delay(200);
      }
      delay(1500);
      handServo.write(180);
      delay(400);
      boxServo.write(70);
      delay(1500);
      for (int i = 70; i <= 110; i++){
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(6);
      }
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(3000);
      handServo.write(180);
      delay(400);
      boxServo.write(70);
      action++;
    }

    else if (action == 12)
    {
      Serial.println("Action 12");    
      for (int i = 70; i <= 110; i++)
      {
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(50);
      }
      delay(1000);
      for (int i = 180; i >= 26; i--)
      {
        handServo.write(i);
        delay(50);
      }
      delay(2000);
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(200);
      handServo.write(180);
      delay(400);
      boxServo.write(70);
      action++;
    }

    else if (action == 13)
    {
      Serial.println("Action 13");     
      for (int i = 70; i <= 110; i++){
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(6);
      }
      delay(2000);
      for (int i = 180; i >= 60; i--)
      {
        handServo.write(i);
        delay(40);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
        handServo.write(60);
        delay(200);
        handServo.write(40);
        delay(800);
      }
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(2000);
      handServo.write(180);
      delay(500);
      boxServo.write(70);
      action++;
    }

    else if (action == 14)
    {
      Serial.println("Action 14");     
      for (int i = 70; i <= 105; i++){
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(6);
      }
      delay(4000);
      boxServo.write(110);
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(650);
      handServo.write(180);
      delay(500);
      boxServo.write(100);
      delay(4000);
      boxServo.write(70);
      action++;
    }

    else if (action == 15)
    {
      Serial.println("Action 15");   
      for (int i = 70; i <= 105; i++){
        boxServo.write(i);
        delay(6);
      }
      delay(1000);
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {      
        for (int j = 70; j <= 105; j++){
          boxServo.write(j);
          delay(50);
        }
        for (int j = 105; j >= 70; j--)
        {
          boxServo.write(j);
          delay(50);
        }
      }
      for (int j = 70; j <= 110; j++){
        boxServo.write(j);
        delay(50);
      }
      for (int i = 180; i >= 35; i--)
      {
        handServo.write(i);
        delay(40);
      }
      delay(1000);
      handServo.write(26);
      delay(400);
      handServo.write(180);
      delay(400);
      boxServo.write(70);
      action = 1;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: please edit your post ... convert the wall of words into clear sentences  .....what is the actual problem that the program is exhibiting?

Comment: And please point us to the action, that is doing problematic, so that we know, where to search in your long code

Comment: you are mistaken about this `the boxservo works contrary to the code` ...... it should say `the boxservo works exactly as programmed`

Comment: when the switch is off boxservo opens the door and when the switch is on boxservo closes the door that is the problem.it's supposed to open the door when the switch is on and close the door when the switch is off.

Comment: If the switch is mounted upside down, then pushing the switch up would close the box; but you need it to open the box instead. In that case, turn the switch so that pushing it up would open the box.

Comment: no i didn't mount the switch

Comment: and my problem isn;t the switch,my problem is that when the switch is on , boxservo closes the door then handservo comes out to turn off the switch and when the handservo turns the switch off and returns to it's place,boxservo opens the door but it's supposed to boxservo opens the door when the switch is on and then handservo comes out to turn it off and after that handservo turns it off and returns back ,boxservo closes the door

Answer (score 1):

You have probably installed the box servo backwards so that when it tries to open it actually closes and vice versa.

Comment: no im sure that it is not bacward

Comment: Then you probably have a servo that is wired in reverse. You need to change the code to reverse the door movement servo.

Comment: i don't know exactly how to change the code.can you help me to change it?please